# JS: window.scroll(x,y) pointing to another frame will not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, frame

So I have two frames. One is sort of file index and it just points to a specific coordinates on the second frame. So here is part of the first frame:

```
<ul class="lista">
    <li><a class="locind" href="javascript:window.scroll(570,800);" target ="showframe">Location A</a></li>
</ul>
```

So what I basically have is just a hyperlink pointing to a frame named *showframe*. I designated that frame as you usually do:

```
<frame src="map.html" name="showframe" id="showframe" >
```

So the point is, in FireFox it works just fine. In Chrome however, it will not point to those coordinates in "*showframe*" frame, but will point to the coordinates in that frame where link is located. So, why is *target="showframe"* not working in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure if either Firefox or Chrome is right, but your code is ambiguous because `window` could refer to either the current frame or the target frame depending on where the JavaScript is executed. You can remove this ambiguity by directly referencing your target frame:

```
<script>
function myScroll(id, x, y) {
  document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.scroll(x, y);
}
</script>

<li><a class="locind" href="javascript:myScroll('showframe', 570,800);" >Location A</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, now when I click on the link nothing happens in chrome and ff, as if can't find that frame. Do I have to add some additional parameters to the frame?